# Pay Later status on imported contributions

Tags: contributions, import, pending

I am trying to do a bulk import of transactions that are all being invoiced now. By indicating the Contribution Status as "Pending," the transactions all import as "Pending (Incomplete Transaction)" Is there any way to get them to import as "Pending (Pay Later)"? I've tried several different variations of the text in the Contribution Status column, but all seem to fail.

Comment: What version of CiviCRM and what CMS are you using? (Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contribution status text `Pending` seems to be right in your csv.

`Pending(Pay later)` status is displayed based on the `is_pay_later` value in civicrm_contribution table. So it seems you need to add another column in CSV with value `1` and map it to the field `Is Pay Later` on the `Match Fields` screen. See below Screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Does this still work? I did this and the transactions still imported as completed