# How do you import contributions as Pending (Pay Later)?

Tags: civicontribute, import, data-import, paylater, pending

After reviewing [Pay Later status on imported contributions](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22296/pay-later-status-on-imported-contributions) - I followed the answer - created a column listed as Is Pay Later - and added the value 1 to all contributions.  Did it again as Yes - both times all contributions were imported as complete instead of pending pay later.

Drupal 7 - 5.20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have 'Pay Later' Column set to 1 and Status column set to 'Pending' for the contribution rows that are pending from pay later. If you don't have status column that its set as Completed by default

Comment: Totally missed that - thank you!